# SSIS Excel Destination Editor closes unexpectedly

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis, ssis-data-flow

I'm fairly new to SSIS, but what I'm trying to do should be simple:

I have a Data Flow task that has an OLE DB Source feeding into an Excel Destination. The issue though, is I can't configure the Excel Destination correctly. I'm able to connect my Excel connection manager, but when I hit the "New..." button next to the "Name of the Excel sheet" dropdown, the Excel Destination Editor window just closes instead of opening a different dialog. In the image below, I highlighted the button that's closing the window.

[image: SSIS Button]

In general, I'm following this guide [How to use SSIS to Export to Excel](http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-excel/) (current step is just above the second to last image in the article).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue lies with the Excel connection instead. Once I changed the output file to .xls instead of .xlsx and changed the connection to Excel 97-2003, I was able to create a new Excel Sheet for the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(1) Close and re-open SQL Server Data Tools (Visual Studio) and test.
(2) If (1) dosn't help, restart machine and test.
(3) You may try a quick uninstall and reinstall and see if that helps. Should be quicker that troubleshooting the issue further.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, none of the 3 steps worked. I came across the solution, which is now posted.